# What's difference in using else-if vs or in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I was creating a rock-paper-scissor game to test my knowledge of functions.
I had written this code to see whether the user had given a valid input of rock, paper or scissor:

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
 userInput =  userInput.toLowerCase();
 if(userInput === 'rock'){
   return userInput;
 } else if(userInput === 'paper') {
    return userInput;
 } else if(userInput === 'scissor'){
    return userInput;
 } else {
   console.log('Invalid Option');
 }
};
```

When I tested the last `else` statement by doing a `console.log` like so:

```
console.log(getUserChoice('water'));
```

It printed out rock instead of printing "Invalid Option".

When I checked the solution I saw this:

```
if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || ... ) {
  return userInput;
} else {
  console.log('Error!');
}
```

So what's the difference between using an else-if to accomplish this task vs using the `||` operator?

Edit:
I made a mistake of using = instead of ===, so it got fixed, but i would still like to know if there is any difference, and which is more efficient for particular use cases.

Comment: When I run your code example in my browser's dev tools, it prints out `'Invalid Option'` to the console, not `'rock'`. Are you sure the code in your question is the same as the code that was producing that unexpected outcome?

Comment: @Mark Hanna, I edited my code after one of the answers pointed out that i was using = instead of ===

Comment: Ah, that explains it then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference between using `||` and using `if`/`else`.

In JavaScript, the `||` operator works like this:

For `a || b`, check if `a` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). If yes, resolve to `a`. Otherwise, resolve to `b`.

Now, as you may have noticed, the wording of that is pretty much identical to how you would describe the behavour of an `if`/`else` conditional block. Functionally, there is no difference in behaviour.

On a related note, the `&&` operator works in a similar way, except then only if `a` is truthy will `a && b` resolve to `b`. If you ever look at minified code, you will sometimes see `&&` used to replace an `if` statement, because `a && b` is functionally identical to `if (a) { b; }` but takes up fewer characters.

I wouldn't recommend using that approach in un-minified code, since it's definitely harder to follow, but it does take up fewer characters without functioning differently, which is why it's used by minifiers. Kind of similar to how they often use `!0` instead of `true`.

Comment: does === compare truthy or true values?

Comment: `===` compares to see if two values are equal, without doing type coersion, whereas `==` will do type coersion. For example, `'' == false` will resolve to true whereas `'' === false` will resolve to false. In almost all circumstances, you'll want to use `===` to help avoid bugs.

Comment: so it doesn't matter whether it is truthy or true?

Comment: If you're using `==`, then *some* truthy values will be reported as being the same as `true`, but not all of them. For example `1 == true` resolves to `true`, but `2 == true` resolves to `false`. I'd recommend always using `===` when doing comparisons like this. When it comes to the result of an expression in an `if` condition, however, the value only has to be **truthy**.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `=` vs `===` operator.
`===` is used to check for equality, and `=` is for assignment.

When you write
`if(userInput = 'rock')`
it means `userInput` is assigned the value of `rock`.
What you really want is `if(userInput === 'rock')`

Regarding the `||` operator (also called OR), what happens is a short-circuit operation. If you write `A || B || C`, the below happens:

1. A is evaluated. If value is `true`, B and C are not evaluated.
2. If A is `false`, then B is `evaluated`.
3. If `B` is true, then `C` is not evaluated.
4. Otherwise, C is evaluated and value of C is returned.

Comment: The OP's use of `=` in the `if` check was probably a typo, where `==` was intended.  The question is more about comparing the two `if` blocks.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that mistake @Jagrut Sharma

Comment: so logically there is no mistake?

Comment: Yes, otherwise looks fine.

Comment: Also check out `switch-case`. It is useful if you have lot of options.

Comment: okay then, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your journey with learning a new language!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the if else statement is only checked/run if the previous if/if elses are false. The or (`||`) statement is true if any of the single conditions are true